# Switch from a not enabled button to an enabled one

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to develop a simple "tris game" (user vs. computer).
In this case the app shows a grid made by 9 buttons and they get colored once clicked.
Actually I found some troubles describing "computer's behaviour", in particular I cannot find a way to handle the moment when the computer chooses a button that has been already clicked. Here is a piece of code:

```
switch (position.get(i)){

                case 1:
                    if (button11.isEnabled()) {

                        button11.setEnabled(false);
                        button11.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                    }else{


                    }
                    break;

                case 2:
                    if (button12.isEnabled()) {

                        button12.setEnabled(false);
                        button12.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                    }
                    break;
```

Here, the variable "position" is a list that contains the position of the buttons and then, with a switch, controls that the selected button is enabled and, in affermative cases, it provides to get the button colored and never clickable.
Now, I was trying to get some code in the "else" part in case the button is already not clickable (for example the users already clicked it previously).
I was thinking if there were a way to pass from case 1 to case 2 and so on until
I found a button which is still clickable. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could create an ArrayList and put your buttons inside it then perform a test inside a loop.

example :

```
 ArrayList<Button> buttonList= new ArrayList<Button>();
 //put your buttons inside the list in order : buttonList.add(button0);...


for(int i=0;i<position.size();i++){

if(buttonsList.get(i).isEnabled()){
                      buttonList.get(i).setEnabled(false);
                      buttonList.get(i).setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
             }
  }
```

Comment: Actually I've found a solution and everything works fine, but thanks because this was a good idea, I didn't think something like this, so this could be useful in future, thank you so much for the answer!